# Where I can find receipts/invoices for QuickBooks online usage?

Tags: quickbooks-online

It seems that [QuickBooks by Intuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBooks) accounting web application provides services for invoicing, but is lacking the invoices for its own services.
I tried to find them last year without success and this year they've changed the site completely and it's the same problem. I've tried to Google for where, but I could find only information on how to print/create the invoices for the customers, but not for the services themselves.

Where I can find receipts/invoices for QuickBooks online monthly service usage itself, to be able to print them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that VAT Invoices are only sent via the e-mail. You can search for them by filtering the e-mail sent from Intuit and print them off.

E.g. in gmail you can use the following search query: `from:Intuit subject:Invoice`.